# Slackware 14.2 - Ensure mail transfer agent is configured for local-only mode

Tags: linux, email, slackware, slack

Mail Transfer Agents (MTA), such as sendmail and Postfix, are used to listen for incoming mail and transfer the messages to the appropriate user or mail server. If the system is not intended to be a mail server, it is recommended that the MTA be configured to only process local mail.

How will I do that in Slackware? In Ubuntu,  to verify that the MTA is not listening on any non-loopback address ( 127.0.0.1 or ::1 ): I can run the command :

```
netstat -an | grep LIST | grep ":25[[:space:]]"
```

Comment: Why would that command not work on Slackware?

Answer (score 1):

Find the IP adresses of each interface (I imagine using ifconfug or ip addr shiw", then try to connect to each onport 25 using netcat or telnet. If 127.0.0.1 answers but the other IPs dont its working ok.

To do this with netcat -

```
 nc IP.AD.DR.ESS 25
```

(Use  or type quit to close the session

To do this with telnet -

```
 telnet IP.ADD.DR.ESS 25
```

type quit to close the session (or ] )